# Unable to connect to wifi, 12.04 macbook pro

Tags: 12.04, wireless, drivers, kernel, macbook

Just intalled ubuntu 12.04 on my macbook pro. Tried installing additional drivers to be able to use my wifi card. It says the activation failed and to check /var/log/jockey.log

I went here to try and fix that

http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1606745

In syanaptic package manager there is a like red ubunutu logo next to bcmwl-kernel-source and when i try and reinstall it says: Sorry a problem occured and it states that it was Package: bcmwl-kernel-source

Can anyone help? Id love to be able to connect to wireless.

Answer (score -1):

2014-08-01

I strongly suggest that you re-install Ubuntu 12.04 and do so without trying to connect to the Internet at the same time. I've found installing and re-stalling Ubuntu this way very helpful since 2012. This method simplifies the process and helps avoiding unforeseen problems. You can take up the wireless matter afterwards.

By the way, all laptops' internal wireless adapters are compatible with Windows, Linux and OSX.

Please let me know whether my suggestion helps. Good luck.

Julianloui